What is this ballet related movie?
I saw this foreign film on YouTube a couple of years ago and I struggled to find the video again. I believe it is from the 1990s or 2000s. There was a piano background. Here’s a description of it:
You see a close up shot of a pair of feet in ballet flats. The camera angle doesn't change and just follows the feet as it does stretches to en pointes. The opening credits roll in as this is happening.
Now you start seeing something on the wooden floor - stain looking. You start seeing more of it and see that it’s coming from the feet. The feet begins slowly getting bloodier but the dance doesn't stop. Eventually the whole front part of the ballet flat is drenched in blood.

I just saw a scene of it, but it seemed to be drama

Do you know the approximate year? The country\language? Did you see it on TV?

Saw a snippet on Youtube. It was a foreign film, I do not know which country it was though.

If you found the film, please ANSWER the question rather than editing your question.

I found the film. It's called The Fine Art of Love and this is the video I saw in 2011: 

.
